Is making a e-commerce website is halal, where I just promote other sellers products and charge them
if i create a website like Amazon ,where the seller post their products and sells their products and they deliver it (not me).I just charge a fixed parchantege for that sold product from the seller.i just only promote my website. Is it halal?
.....
If not then how to make it halal?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

This question is similar to: Is X halal? (reference question). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
