Is making a e-commerce website is halal, where I just promote other sellers products and charge them for sold product
If i create a website like Amazon, where the seller post their products and sells their products and they deliver it (not me). I just charge a fixed percentage for that sold product from the seller. I'm only promoting my website. Is it halal?
If not then how to make it halal?

Please don't repetitively post the same question (https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/85341/22). If it wasn't answered an hour ago, just wait longer, everybody on this site is a volunteer, and not everyone has the required expertise to help you. Impatience is likely just going to earn downvotes and make it harder for you to receive any answer.

It doesn't make any sense to create mutliple accounts to push your questions beeing answered here. Please refrain from that and delete your first question since this one got an answer. Also consider contacting the moderator team asking for an account merge.

If you are creating a worth-it and valuable platform like Amazon or Flipkart where a person installs his products or services to sell and they are making valuable sale and the product is lawful in shari'a laws and services then there is no problem in charging the amount as you are charging because you have aided them with proper platform to sell and create customers and revenues so it is your right to charge to them because you have given something valuable for the sellers then the second thing is you have to look after how to charge as per Shari'a basis because charging fix amount from every seller is problematic like a person who is selling laptop of 5,300$ and second person who is selling a mobile phone of 530$ but if you are charging the same amount per product like 38$ from both of them one is a low-seller second one is high-seller then it is injustice and haraam, rather than what I will advise is to take your returns from limit like if you have created this much sale then give me this much or look akhi there is no problem in charging per product with limit and value just like Allah Azzawajal said in Surah AR Rahman verse 9 that "Weigh with justice, and do not give short measure." so based on this weight on justice or charge with justice like if a person is selling a mobile of 530$ then charge 12 to 15$ or check what suitable and valuable revenue is from your platform worth sharing to him so that he can make sale and charge according to it and if someone selling laptop or refrigerator or Air-Condition of high pricing unit then charge according to what is suitable it will be shari'a friendly and Allah will reward you.
And another step that you can take if you want fix amount in this is that at a time when your website gain popularity and it has it's own merit and goodwill in the market like Amazon and Flipkart then announce and label it openly that "our website will charge this much if you want your store to be open here and make this much sale of first sale or something" but it can only be halal at a moment when your website has value and goodwill in the market or every e-commerce platform selling website market have same thing in these cases it will be friendly. And the best option for you which can be Shari'a friendly is as I have quoted "Weigh with justice" 55:9 so weight with justice and accordance with proper niche and products or services.
Hope this will help you and please don't make hasten in getting answer Inshallah you will getting your answers, just make dua for us that Allah give barakah in our knowledge so that we can keep assisting you with proper and authentic teaching of righteous interpretations of Qur'an and Ahadeeth that's it. End Quote. Allah knows best.
